# copy zip file from resource to sdcard in blackberry webworks

Tags: blackberry, resources, local, blackberry-webworks

I am trying to develop a Blackberry webworks application in which I need to add 14mb of zip file in the resource and prepackage it with the application.

Once the application is launched the zip file should be copied from the resource folder to SDCard and unzipped.  Using `local:///` protocol I am not able to access the file.

Please help if there is any other way to access the data or prepackage the data.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Salutations on posts are not needed as every post is already signed with your signature block.